# Write custom function with dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a function to calculate "retained" and "addition" columns to my data frame based on the value of "obsnum" in each row (see function below), by user_id. It works correctly using ddply, but ddply was too memory intensive, so someone suggested that I use the dplyr package instead. Here is the error message I got when I used this function with dplyr.

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  invalid formal argument list for "function"

I am completely new to dplyr, so I don't know what is wrong with my function format or how to put custom functions into dplyr. I want to apply this function based on a variable "obsnum" to each row in my dataset. The function needs to be grouped by user_id, hence I need to use dplyr.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with getting my function to be recognized by dplyr?
Should I use mutate() since I am adding columns? df1 is my original data frame. df2 is the dataset I am trying to create with these two new columns for "retained" and "addition". Thank you very much.

df2 <- df1 %.%

```
group_by(user_id) %.%
function(x) {
x = x[order(x$obsnum), ]
if (length(x$obsnum) == 1) {
  x$retained <- FALSE
  x$addition <- TRUE
}
else {
  x$retained <- c(x$obsnum[1:(length(x$obsnum)-1)] + 1 == x$obsnum[2:length(x$obsnum)], FALSE)
  x$addition <- c(TRUE, x$obsnum[2:length(x$obsnum)] != x$obsnum[1:(length(x$obsnum)-1)] + 1)
}
return(x)
```

}

Comment: you might be looking for the function `do.call(FUNC, list(arguments))`   Also, have a look at the `data.table` package which would allow you to modify data by reference (quicker, more efficient) and not to mention easier syntax

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful to keep in mind. I ended up defining my function first, doing an arrange and group_by second, and then calling the function as the third step. Probably not very elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Without sample data and desired output there's no way to test the code, but here's more `dplyr`-like code that hopefully does what you want. If not, please update your question with some sample data and desired output.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  arrange(user_id, obsnum) %>%
  mutate(retained = obsnum +1 == lead(obsnum, 1, default = FALSE),
         addition = lead(obsnum, 1, default = TRUE) != obsnum +1)
```

Basically, since you're just adding columns, you can use `mutate` and don't necessarily need a custom function for that. If you wanted to use a custom function, you'd still need to first define the function (before the dplyr-pipe) and then use it - either inside the mutate - or if it's an arbitrary function, you'd need to use dplyr's `do` operator.